# CGFloat array help - iPhone dev

Tags: iphone

here is my code:

```
CGFloat components[8];//[8];// = {  0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5 };
if ([appDelegate.graphType isEqualToString:@"response"])
{
    CGFloat components[8] = {  0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 };
}
else 
{
    if ([appDelegate.graphType isEqualToString:@"uptime"])
    {
        CGFloat components[8] = {  0.694, 0.855, 0.961, 0.5, 0.188, 0.588, 0.906, 0.5 };
    }
    else
    {
        CGFloat components[8] = {  0.694, 0.855, 0.961, 0.5, 0.188, 0.588, 0.906, 0.5 };
    }
}
```

So basically, I want to draw different gradients based on different graph types. However, xCode shows me that CGFloat components[8] from if/else statements is unused and ignores its values. Any ideas what is the problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are declaring new components arrays in each if/else block.  You don't want to do this, you just want to assign the values to the already declared components array.

Something like this should work:

```
CGFloat components[8];

const CGFloat components1[8] = {  0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 };
const CGGloat components2[8] = {  0.694, 0.855, 0.961, 0.5, 0.188, 0.588, 0.906, 0.5 };
const CGFloat components3[8] = {  0.694, 0.855, 0.961, 0.5, 0.188, 0.588, 0.906, 0.5 };

if ([appDelegate.graphType isEqualToString:@"response"])
{
    memcpy(components,components1, 8*sizeof(CGFloat));
}
else 
{
    if ([appDelegate.graphType isEqualToString:@"uptime"])
    {
             memcpy(components,components2, 8*sizeof(CGFloat));
    }
    else
    {
             memcpy(components,components3, 8*sizeof(CGFloat));
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't working like this, I have tried it before. It reports error for components lines

Comment: No of course it wasn't.  You can't initialize an array outside of it's declaration.  I've edited the source to use memcpy, which might work better.