# Start a float with a number of different numbers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, floating-point

This is the code i have:

```
CGFloat buttonGradient1Colors [] = { 
        [gradient1TopColor ], 1.0, 1.0, 0.16,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.11
    };
```

But i want to add an if statement, where the float changes it's value based on something, and so i need to set up the CGFloat beforehand. I tried:

```
CGFloat buttonGradient1Colors;
```

and

```
CGFloat buttonGradient1Colors [];
```

but the second one gave me an error on the line, and the first one gave me an error further on. Any ideas?

EDIT:

So now i have this:

```
CGFloat buttonGradient1Colors [8];

    buttonGradient1Colors [8] = { 
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.16,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.11
    };
```

but it's giving me an 'expected expression' error on the 2nd line.

Comment: Post the actual code where you are getting errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the size when you creating a C array.

If you want to change the value. You can do like this

```
CGFloat buttonGradient1Colors[8] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.16, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.11};
if (condition)  {
    buttonGradient1Colors[index] = newValue;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Specified the size now. I'm still getting an error. I posted more code above.

Comment: Updated... hope this can help you.

Comment: That works, but it's going to take up 8 lines of code, to assign each one separately. Is there another way of changing the value, where i can specify them all together?

Comment: Probably try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333873/cgfloat-array-help-iphone-dev

Answer (score 1):

You can only assign multiple values when initializing the array:

```
CGFloat[] myFloats = { 1.0, 2.5, 3.6 };
```

This doesn't work, unfortunately:

```
CGFloat[3] myFloats;
myFloats = { 2.2, 3.5, 4.7 }; // error!
```

If the conditions are reasonably simple, you can use the ternary operator to do it all on "one line" like so:

```
CGFloat[] myFloats = {
  (someBoolean ? 1.0 : 2.0),
  ([someObject message] == 2 ? 2.2 : 3.3),
  (someInt > 10 ? 4.5 : 8.0)
};
```

Oh, one more note: if you're initializing a C array with values, you *do not* have to give the size; the compiler will figure it out.